# Angular route guard page becomes blank on browser refresh

Tags: angular, routes, guard

I have a simple Angular application that implements router guard to check if the user has appropriate access. If access is allowed, the guard will return `true` then load `DashboardComponent`. Otherwise, it will redirect to the `ContactComponent`.

All is well until I hit the browser refresh button while already in the `ContactComponent`. The page becomes blank after I do so. I believe it's because I did not put `CanActivate` decoration in my `ContactComponent`. But if I put a `CanActivate` in the `ContactComponent`, the application goes berserk and loads infinitely.

How do I handle refresh in the same page where the route guard redirected the user?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard' }
{ path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
{ path: 'dashboard', CanActivate: [AccessGuard], component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

**access.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.getAccess().pipe(map(access => {
      if (access.valid) {
          return true;
      }
      else {
          this.router.navigate(['contact'], { state: { isValid: 'false' });
          return false;
      }
   }
}
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    const extras = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
    if (!extras.isValid) {
       this.errorMessage = 'Access is not allowed. Please contact Administrator.';
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple way is to check the current route in `access.guard.ts` and when you are already in `contact` page, return `true`.